# C# Outlook Appointment User Properties - Not persisting across calendars/invitees

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

Is there a way to persist user properties across to the appointment invitees/locations calendars?

I have created a form region for appointments, with some extra form fields on. Upon the appointment write event, I can save the form region data as user properties against the appointment. From the senders' point of view, these properties persist when the item is opened up, and can be updated etc.

However, any invitees on the appointment, or any meeting rooms/locations included can receive the appointment BUT the user properties don't seem to carry across with the item. Why is this, and can it be worked around?

The only one I could think of is to persist the user properties in a database also and load them upon item open with the `FormRegion_Showing` method. That's not ideal though as the whole point was to keep it all in outlook.

I'm using Outlook 2010 and Visual Studio 2015.

I came across [this post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/147deaa7-b362-4793-9c8c-432d3f6fe0c0/formregion-appointmentitem-userproperties-do-not-send-via-meetingitem?forum=outlookdev) which pretty much says it can't be done, however that is from 2011 and I can't find anything more recent that's relevant to this particular scenario.

Some cut down code - the Form Region:

```
// Form region class
[Microsoft.Office.Tools.Outlook.FormRegionMessageClass(Microsoft.Office.Tools.Outlook.FormRegionMessageClassAttribute.Appointment)]
[Microsoft.Office.Tools.Outlook.FormRegionName("Namespace.MyFormRegion")]
public partial class MyFormRegionFactory
{

}

private void MyFormRegion_FormRegionShowing(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Outlook.AppointmentItem appointment = this.OutlookItem as Outlook.AppointmentItem;
    this.appointment.Write += Appointment_Write;
}

private void Appointment_Write(ref bool Cancel)
{
    Outlook.ItemProperties CateringData = this.appointment.ItemProperties;
    var Serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();

    Outlook.ItemProperty MeetingNameProperty = CateringData.Add("MeetingName", Outlook.OlUserPropertyType.olText, true);
    MeetingNameProperty.Value = this.MeetingName.Text;

    // More properties saved
    appointment.Save();
}
```

and in the addin class:

```
public partial class ThisAddIn
{
    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.ItemSend += Application_ItemSend;
    }

    private void Application_ItemSend(object Appointment, ref bool Cancel)
    {
        // Appointment is an AppointmentItem that has just been saved.
        // How does this relate to the outgoing item that ends up in the 
        // Sent Items folder???
    }
}
```

Using Outlook Spy the user properties are not in the item within the Sent Items. The form region does appear when opening the item from one of the invitees calendars, but the user properties are not there.

Comment: Are you sending between two Exchange mailboxes? Or through SMTP?

Comment: The invitees are all internal so it's through the same exchange server, I think.

Comment: Having read a bit since posting this question it looks like setting an ExtendedProperty on the item using EWS might be a way to do it? Presumably that would be something along the lines of attaching the properties to the item after calling AppointmentItem.Save in the add-in?

Comment: Do you see the user properties using OutlookSpy on the MeetingRequest object in the Sent Items folder?

Comment: I've just installed it - it doesn't look like they are, no. But also the form region is not present on the sent item (the form region is attached for appointment items only)

Comment: Also, not sure if it makes a difference but I'm using .UserProperties and NOT PropertyAccessor (for both get and set)

Comment: You can process Application.ItemSend event hand if it is a MeetingItem object, set the required user properties.

Comment: The properties are being set, they just don't carry over to other invitees and only persist in my calendar (or the sender's calendar)

Comment: Set on the AppointmentItem in your Calendar? Or on the MeetingItem in your Sent Items folder?

Comment: the AppointmentItem in my calendar. The form region from my outlook addin is an adjoining one to appointment items. The properties persist on the item within my own calendar, but they do not transfer to other invitees/recipients calendars,or the resource rooms calendars. The form region doesn't even appear in the sent items folder for the item.

Comment: Again, are they set on the MeetignItem in the Sent Items folder? If not, you can try to use the Application.ItemSend event to set the properties on the outgoing MeetignItem object.

Comment: OK - I shall shift my logic out of the Appointment_Write (where I set the properties) to Application.ItemSend within the addin class and see if that works.

Comment: You would probably need both - you can simply copy existing properties from AppointmentItem to MeetignItem in the ItemSend event handler.

Comment: I don't see how this will work Dmitry? The item passed to ItemSend is the item from the form region, which is an Appointment Item (you cannot set this to a MeetingItem as a MessageClass on the form region). The properties are already set on that item when that object is received into ItemSend. After the appointment is saved, opening the item in the Sent Items folder there is no form region attached and the user properties are not there either. I fail to see how this MeetingItem object comes into play? Where does it come from?

Comment: I will add some code to my question to make things a bit easier to see.

Comment: No, AppointmentItem is never sent. Outlook creates a MeetignItem object and sends it instead The original AppointmentItem  is left in the Calendar folder.

Comment: How did you check that the MeetignItem in the Sent Items folder has the user properties? Did you take a look with OutlookSpy? Click both Item and IMessage buttons.

Comment: Yes, I've looked at both of those through OutlookSpy and none of the properties are there.

Comment: Dmitry - thanks for your time and patience! I've realised why the properties haven't been persisting - I was unknowingly overwriting an internal outlook property (MeetingType) and this caused none of the properties to persist. Having now changed the property name for that value they all persist to both the sent items folder and the invitees' calendar!

Answer (score 1):

So, after lots of head scratching and modifications, and after using Outlook Spy with the help of Dmitry (http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/home.htm) to inspect User Properties I realised that I had been trying to set a property name that happened to be in use already by Outlook internally (MeetingType)

After changing the name of that property, all the other user properties now persist in both the sent items and invitees' calendars.

For anyone else coming across this same issue where properties don't persist, check your property names with those set in Outlook already, could save you hours of headache!